# undefined method `artist' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am getting this error when I run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'authentication')
require "csv" # faster_csv (ruby 1.9)

lines = CSV.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'karaoke.csv')) # Exported an Excel file as CSV
lines.slice!(0) # remove header line
collection = StorageRoom::Collection.find('collection ID')
Song = collection.entry_class
lines.each do |row|
  karaoke = Song.new(:artist => row[0], :song => row[1], :genre => row[2], :file => StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename("#{karaoke.artist}#{karaoke.song}.mov"))
  if karaoke.save
    puts "Misuero Karaoke Latino saved: #{karaoke.artist}, #{karaoke.song}, #{karaoke.genre}"
  else
    puts "Misuero Karaoke Latino could not be saved: #{karaoke.errors.join(', ')}"
  end
end
```

And the error is:

```
import_csv.rb:15:in `block in <main>': undefined method `artist' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from import_csv.rb:14:in `each'
    from import_csv.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

I'm interested in learning why this error occurred as well as the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your `karaoke` object is not instantiated.

Comment: @AdrienSchuler I don't understand. Isn't it instantiated in line 15? Song is instantiated in line 12 right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use directly use `StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename("#{karaoke.artist}#{karaoke.song}.mov")` in your karaoke object constructor. You are trying to access an object property when he is not yet instantiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at line 15 (`import_csv.rb:15` tells you where to search for the issue):

```
karaoke = Song.new(:artist => row[0], :song => row[1], :genre => row[2], 
  :file => StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename("#{karaoke.artist}#{karaoke.song}.mov"))
```

In the right part of assignment expression you use `karaoke.artist` and `karaoke.song` to construct `:file` part of your `Song`, but `karaoke` variable is uninitialized yet (it appears on the left). In fact ruby interpreter *defined* `karaoke` variable when it saw the assignment operator and started evaluation of right-hand part of assignment expression (to *initialize* variable) and failed, because *defined* variable has `nil` value.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the problem lies in your assignment of the `karaoke` variable. When you are assigning anything to a new variable, the right side of the assignment is computed before the left side. So, at the moment your code gets to line 15, the `karaoke` variable is `nil`.

So, when you use the `karaoke` variable in the method `StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename`, it is a `nil` object. `karaoke` does not contain anything until the entire right side of the assignment is computed. Then it is tied to the `karaoke` variable.

You should consider using something like `row[0]` and `row[2]` instead of `karaoke.artist` and `karaoke.genre`.

Answer (score 1):

It means you are calling artist method on a nil/Null

possibly try replacing #{karaoke.artist}#{karaoke.song} with #{row[0]}#{row[1]})

```
karaoke = Song.new(:artist => row[0], :song => row[1], :genre => row[2], :file => StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename("#{row[0]}#{row[1]}.mov"))
```

Comment: note even though I answered first you may want to repick who to award the question to since the other answers are more thorough.

Comment: That's very thoughtful of you! I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use karaoke object in initializing of itself.

In ruby when you write(assuming that you've never used "a" variable before)

```
a = some_expression_or_value
```

the interpreter calculates the value of the "right part" which is some expression or value and then assigns it to the variable. Your variable karaoke hasn't been used before which means that it's value is nil. That's why you get this error.